# Undocumented CSV field in the Firebase CLI auth export

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-cli

As documented [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/auth#csv), the firebase command `firebase auth:export account_file --format=csv` should return 26 fields but I get a 27th, between `GitHub Photo URL` and `User Creation Time`.

It is a boolean but seems to have only `false` or empty value

My only guess is that we migrated from Parse to Firebase and some accounts still have the 10 characters long Parse ID. These have this mysterious field set to `false` but it is empty for the newest ones with the Firebase ID.

Note that this field doesn't seem to appear in the NodeJS SDK function `admin.auth().listUsers()`

Thanks